# Extracting university from Facebook education -'education' field not recognised

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to extract the university of the user from their Facebook profile and found this post to be useful - [Getting Education with Facebook Graph API in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171438/getting-education-with-facebook-graph-api-in-php)

However, in my implementation the 'education' field is not being recognised for some reason and is throwing an error in the browser of " Undefined index: education".  This is odd because the first and last name and gender are all being retrieved fine but not the 'education' field.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

My code:

```
// Get the app User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        // If the user has been authenticated then proceed
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        // Extracting profile information to store in database
        $fname   = $user_profile['first_name'];
        $lname   = $user_profile['last_name'];
        $gender  = $user_profile['gender'];
        $email   = $user_profile['email'];
        $college = null;

        /* Education data is stored in an array so this iterates over
        the contents of that array and checks if the entry is for "College".  
        */

        foreach ($user_profile['education'] as $education) { // <-ERROR HERE
            if ($education['type'] == "College") {
                $college = $education;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the user education column you can read facebook users' school name, id and type. just grab the school name in a variable running fql. for further info plz check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/